# What are the advantages of using <i> before an element instead of wrapping the element in <span>?

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons, font-face

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [<I> tag for icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/i-tag-for-icons)

I've seen in [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) that to use their icon fonts, they are employing an empty `<i>`, something like this:

```
<a class="btn" href="#">
   <i class="icon-refresh"></i> Refresh
</a>
```

instead of wrapping it with `<span>` like this:

```
<a class="btn" href="#">
   <span class="icon-refresh">Refresh</span>
</a>
```

I've seen some other websites employ similar technique too. AFAIK, both technique utilizes the CSS pseudo-element `:before`, so I wonder why do they use `<i>` instead of wrapping it with `<span>`?

Are there any advantages on using an empty `<i>`? And is it semantic?

Comment: Related/duplicates: [<i> tag for icons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/i-tag-for-icons), [How does Twitter Bootstrap's icon <i …> work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001575/how-does-twitter-bootstraps-icon-i-work)

Comment: That pseudo element is now called `::before`

Comment: @RobW: hmm, I can't find answers on those questions that compare the `<i>` with the `<span>`, so I assumed it was okay to open a new question?

Comment: "And is it semantic?" Heck no. Whoever thought of using `<i>` for icons deserves to be skewered. That's even worse than using `<i>` for italics, which it was originally created for, even though it wasn't semantic. I dare say zero semantics (which `<span>` represents) beat incorrect semantics - even `<i>` has been bestowed with brand new, proper semantic meaning in HTML5, and "icon" is not it.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: is it already okay to use `::before`? Because AFAIK some browsers (IE, if I recall correctly) don't render `::before`.

Comment: @deathlock You're asking multiple questions, that's why I said *related* (I did not vote to close, because "what are the advantages" has not been literally answered yet)

Comment: @deathlock: Only if you don't plan to support IE8.

Answer (score 2):

The only advantage I can think of is just that `<i>` is shorter to write (and not to send over the wire, cause gzip doesn't care much if its i or span with 20-letters class) and it's distinctive from other markup. It is like self-made tag for icons.

But there are no other semantic value in `<i>` whatsoever.

> The i element represents a span of text in an alternate voice or mood,
>   or otherwise offset from the normal prose, such as a taxonomic
>   designation, a technical term, an idiomatic phrase from another
>   language, a thought, a ship name, or some other prose whose typical
>   typographic presentation is italicized.

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-b-and-i-tags/

So is it semantic? No. But no one cares, no big deal.

Comment: Well, yes. I, personally, do care too. But the impact of this abuse is so small. No one will punish for this, not users, not search engines, no one. So no big deal, really.

Answer (score 0):

A point that's [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652099/just-noticed-the-i-tag-on-twitter-did-they-make-that-up/10230076#10230076) could be one reason - saving bytes..

For me it's ease of use..