# What are the Advantages of Using Tags Like <i> and <em> For Design Elements Like Arrows and Icons?

Tags: css, user-interface

I saw this piece of source code on Buffer's website:

```
div class="bubble">
   <em class="pointer-arrow"></em>
   <span class="character-count" style="display: none;">0</span>
   <div class="content">
...
```

The `pointer-arrow` class is what makes the "tails" on the bubbles around certain UI elements. Notice how they used an `<em>` tag instead of a `<span>`.

[image]

I've seen this technique used in Twitter Bootstrap as well. I believe they used the `<i>` tag for some of their icons.

Why do it this way? Is it a matter of preference or are their genuine advantages of using tags like `<em>` and `<i>` over `<span>` for design features like icons?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532719/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-i-before-an-element-instead-of-wrapping-the-e?rq=1 and the question that it's a duplicate of as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using the  tag may save a few bytes but it is mostly used for the ease of use it provides.